# Using Web Deploy with Visual Studio and Plesk

Tags: iis-8, plesk, plesk-onyx

I am trying to web deploy a Asp.Net Core 2 project through plesk.

My plesk version is;

> Plesk Onyx
>
> Version 17.8.11 Update #6
>
> IIS 8.5.9600

I have also followed the guide and added web deploy to the server;

[Plesk Web Deploy Guide](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213925425-How-to-enable-Web-Deploy-Publishing-in-Plesk)

However, when I go to publish my website i get the following error;

> Web deployment task failed. (Connected to 'www.domain.co.uk' using the Web Deployment Agent Service, but could not authorize. Make sure you are an administrator on 'www.domain.co.uk'.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN.)
>   Make sure the site name, user name, and password are correct. If the issue is not resolved, please contact your local or server administrator.
>   Error details:
>   Connected to 'domain' using the Web Deployment Agent Service, but could not authorize. Make sure you are an administrator on 'www.domain.co.uk'.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN.
>   The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Now I have tried the admin login for the plesk portal and I still get this message?

How and where do I add user privileges (just for this site) to allow the web deploy to work?

**UPDATE**

I have gone to subscriptions -> selected the subscription -> users, create a new user for this and then added a new administrator user her. But again when I try to run the web deploy through visual studio I am getting the same error (the user is definitely in the admin role).